# shortcut for finding a reference to the selected item in sublime 3

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext3

Does anyone know if there's a shortcut for finding a reference to the selected item (or the item under the cursor) when working with sublime 3?  In VS it is Ctrl F12 which is an awesome feature when navigating between files/tabs and you want to know what the reference is for a function/callback and so on.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F12</kbd> is the one you're looking for. It uses the [global symbol list](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html#fm-goto-symbol) — the same that you get when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd>. That means, if you want to jump to the stdlib definitions, you have to add your language's standard library to the project `folders`.